# R: Overloading primitive, non-generic functions

Tags: r, overload-resolution

I'd like to find the minimal hack to be able to say `module::obj` when `module` is not a package but a list or environment.

After some digging, I see the following works for the new use case, but breaks the native one:

```
module = structure(list(f = \(x) x + 1), class = "module_cls")
`::` = function(mod, key) UseMethod("::")
`::.default` = function(mod, key) .Primitive("::")
`::.module_cls` = function(mod, key) mod[[as.character(substitute(key))]]

module::f(1)    # works!
base::sum(1, 1) # Error in base::sum : object 'base' not found
```

The problem seems to be either in the definition of the `default` method
or how anything that is not `module_cls` is depatched to `default`.